# Getting values when selected

Tags: php, html

I'm on the learning mode.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['fifty']) || !empty($_POST['sixty'])) {
    $fifty = (isset($_POST['fifty'])) ? (int)$_POST['fifty'] : 0;
    $sixty = (isset($_POST['sixty'])) ? (int)$_POST['sixty'] : 0;
    echo $fifty + $sixty;
} else {
    echo "No selection selected";
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="fifty" value="50"/>
    <input type="radio" name="sixty" value="60"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This only works when I select both radio buttons. How do I make this work when I just select 1 radio button instead of 2?

And is the way I coded the PHP the good way to write it? I get an idea that I do double work with checking :P

And how do I do it with three radio options? Can you give me a example with a third radio option called seventy with value 70?

My idea is to make it + count the values if 1 and 3 are slected it must to 50+70 
if 2 and 3 are selected it must do 60 + 70, etc, etc.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, `input` is self-closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `||`for OR, `&&` for AND

```
if(!empty($_POST['fifty']) || !empty($_POST['sixty'])){
   $fifty = (isset($_POST['fifty']))? (int)$_POST['fifty'] : 0;
   $sixty = (isset($_POST['sixty']))? (int)$_POST['sixty'] : 0;
   echo $fifty + $sixty;
} else {
  echo "No selection selected"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for tip appreciate it

Comment: What does the ? do after isset and the : before the 0 ? 
And the code is echoing No selection selected when page is loaded. That's why i did the sumit check

Comment: For the first row, that's mean, if `$_POST['$fifty']` exists, then $fifty = $_POST[’$fifty'] else, 0.

Comment: I did not even notice, but this has been working as a choice 1, 2 or 3 clicks THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

A few things to change.

1. The `<input />` tags.

   ```
   <input type="radio" name="fifty" value="50" />
   <input type="radio" name="sixty" value="60" />
   ```
2. The logic you used (which you have corrected).

   ```
   if (!empty($_POST['fifty']) || !empty($_POST['sixty']))
   ```
3. Remove unnecessary code:

   ```
   $submit = $_POST['submit'];
   ```